# a Java assignment creating a Hangman game using classes and inheritance

Tags: java

I want to create a Hangman class that extends another class that calls all the class methods from the other class. I've got a few things down but I'm still stuck. Here's what I have so far...

### Hang.java

```java
public class Hang {

    /**
     * Returns a lowercase version of a user-entered letter
     *
     * @param kbd input stream from which the letter is read
     * @return a lowercase version of a user-entered letter
     */
    public static char getNewGuess(Scanner kbd) {
        char newchar = '?';
        System.out.print("Enter your new guess> ");
        while (!Character.isLetter(newchar)) {
            newchar = kbd.next().charAt(0);
            if (!Character.isLetter(newchar)) {
                System.out.print("Your character must be a letter.  Please enter again> ");
            }
        }
        return Character.toLowerCase(newchar);
    }

    /**
     * Plays the game of Hangman using a HangWord object
     *
     * @param args not used
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HangWord game = new HangWord('*', 8);
        char newGuess;
        Scanner kbd = new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean done = false;
        while (!done) {
            boolean gameOver = false;
            while (!gameOver) {
                game.displayGuess();
                newGuess = getNewGuess(kbd);
                game.updateWord(newGuess);
                //gameOver = game.win() || game.lose();
            }
            System.out.print("Do you want to play again (Y/N) => ");
            char answer = kbd.next().toLowerCase().charAt(0);
            if (answer == 'y') {
                //game.clear();
            } else {
                done = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So this is the main class that I essentially have to use to create the second class that does all the methods `displayGuess`, `win`, `lose`, etc.

I'm stuck with how some of the methods in my other class don't work. So I'm hoping somebody can takes a look and see what I've done wrong.

### HangWord.java

```java
/**
 * HangWord class that uses inheritance to complete Hang.java
 *
 * @field symbol - the symbol used for the hidden/correct word
 * @field tries - amount of tries given
 * @variable wordList - the wordList used to choose words
 */
public class HangWord extends Hang {

    private char symbol;
    private int tries;
    String[] wordList = {"their",
            "would",
            "about",
            "there",
            "think",
            "which",
            "people",
            "could",
            "other",
            "these",
            "first",
            "because",
            "thing",
            "those",
            "woman",
            "through",
            "child",
            "there",
            "after",
            "should",
            "world",
            "school",
            "still",
            "three",
            "state",
            "never",
            "become",
            "between",
            "really",
            "something",
            "another",
            "family",
            "leave",
            "while",
            "student",
            "great",
            "group",
            "begin",
            "country",
            "where",
            "problem",
            "every",
            "start",
            "might",
            "about",
            "against",
            "place",
            "again",
            "company",
            "where",
            "system",
            "right",
            "program",
            "question",
            "during",
            "government",
            "small",
            "number",
            "always",
            "night",
            "point",
            "believe",
            "today",
            "bring",
            "happen",
            "without",
            "before",
            "large",
            "million",
            "under",
            "water",
            "write",
            "mother",
            "national",
            "money",
            "story",
            "young",
            "month",
            "different",
            "right",
            "study",
            "though",
            "business",
            "issue",
            "black",
            "little",
            "house",
            "after",
            "since",
            "provide",
            "service",
            "around",
            "friend",
            "important"};
    Random randGen = new Random();
    
    public HangWord(char S, int t) {
        symbol = S;
        tries = 0;
    }

    public void setName(char S) {
        symbol = S;
    }

    public char getSymbol() {
        return symbol;
    }

    public void setTries(int t) {
        tries = t;
    }

    public int getTries() {
        return tries;
    }

    /**
     * uses the wordList to select a random word from the arraylist of words.
     *
     * @param none
     * @returns the randomly selected word from the wordList in the constructor
     */
    public String getWord() {
        int len = wordList.length;
        int index = randGen.nextInt(len);
        String word = wordList[index];
        return word;
    }

    /**
     * Displays the guess in the selected symbol used.
     */
    public void displayGuess() {
        String guess = "";
        String s = getWord();
        int length = s.length();
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            guess += String.valueOf(symbol);
        }
        System.out.println("Guess:" + guess);
    }

    /**
     * Updates the correct word with the letter correctly guessed in the word, replacing the symbol with the letter.
     *
     * @param a - the letter guessed from user input that is used to update the hidden word used in displayGuess
     */
    public void updateWord(char a) {
        String s = getWord();
        char[] word = new char[s.length()];
        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
            if (s.charAt(i) == a) {
                word[i] = a;
            } else {
                word[i] = s.charAt(i);
                System.out.println("Sorry..." + a + "is not in the word");
            }
            String newWord = String.valueOf(word);
        }
    }
}
```

** This is specifically from the displayGuess and updateWord methods. When I check the output to see if something is running correctly I get this output

```
Guess:*****

Enter your new guess> f
Sorry...fis not in the word
Sorry...fis not in the word
Sorry...fis not in the word
Sorry...fis not in the word
Sorry...fis not in the word
Guess:*****

Enter your new guess>
```

I'm guessing I used some wrong variables because it's supposed to replace the symbol '*' with the letter guessed but it doesn't do that. Everything else I haven't really done yet as I'm still working on this.

Comment: *I'm stuck on how to do certain things* - I know this is a hangman question but it may be quicker to tell us what you are stuck on.  What have you tried, what isn't working with it.

Comment: @ScaryWombat I've edited the question to to specify the methods in the HangWord class I'm having issues with and the output that I'm having issues with.

Comment: Use the debugger to step through your code. You have a number of bugs, and I think you'll spot some of them if you watch your program running.

Comment: Some things to think about: if you call `getWord` on the same `HangWord` instance twice, should it return the same word? Does it? Is `updateWord` meant to change the state of your `HangWord` instance? What is meant to do? Does it do it?

Comment: Also: Is there any code in `displayGuess` which could possibly show something other than a `*`?

Comment: Poor title. Rewrite to summarize your specific technical issue.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my implementation based off your initial attempt. I've not tested it but it should get you 90-99% of the way to where you want to be.

I've broken it up more and moved everything into `HangmanGame`. This allows you to program more in line with what you'd expect without having to deal with the confusion working with statics brings early on in learning.

I'm not sure what you were trying to achieve by extending a class, but I didn't see it as necessary. Happy to answer any questions.

#### HangmanApplication.java

This is a controller for the game and decides what to call and when.

```java
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Set;

public class HangmanApplication {

    /**
     * Plays the game of Hangman using a HangWord object
     *
     * @param args not used
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HangmanGame game = new HangmanGame(10);

        Scanner inputReader = new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean isGameOver = false;

        while (!isGameOver) {
            // init new game
            Character blankSymbol = '*';
            String wordToGuess = game.getNewGameWord();
            String displayCharacters = game.getWordAsSymbols(wordToGuess, blankSymbol);

            System.out.println("New word: " + displayCharacters);

            // begin game
            while (game.isGameOver(game, blankSymbol, displayCharacters)) {
                // letter will always be new/valid here
                char letterGuessed = game.getNextGuess(inputReader);

                game.updateLivesLeft(letterGuessed, wordToGuess);
                String newDisplayCharacters = game.updateDisplayCharacters(letterGuessed, wordToGuess, displayCharacters);

                // output a message to say well done or bad luck:
                if (displayCharacters.equals(newDisplayCharacters)) {
                    System.out.println("Try again. Lives left " + game.getLivesLeft());
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Nice one. Lives left " + game.getLivesLeft());
                }

                System.out.println(newDisplayCharacters);
                displayCharacters = newDisplayCharacters;
            }

            if (game.isWordGuessed(displayCharacters, blankSymbol)) {
                // you win - print message
            } else {
                // you lost - print message
            }

            System.out.print("Do you want to play again (Y/N) => ");
            char answer = inputReader.next().toLowerCase().charAt(0);
            if (answer == 'y') {
                //game.clear();
            } else {
                isGameOver = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### HangmanGame.java

This keeps game logic in one place

```
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Set;

public class HangmanGame {

    private int livesUsed;
    private final int totalLives;
    private final Set<Character> lettersGuessed;
    private final String wordToGuess;
    private static final String[] wordList = {"their", "would", "about", "there", "think",
            "which", "people", "could", "other", "these", "first", "because", "thing", "those",
            "woman", "through", "child", "there", "after", "should", "world", "school", "still", "three",
            "state", "never", "become", "between", "really", "something", "another", "family", "leave",
            "while", "student", "great", "group", "begin", "country", "where", "problem", "every", "start",
            "might", "about", "against", "place", "again", "company", "where", "system", "right", "program",
            "question", "during", "government", "small", "number", "always", "night", "point", "believe",
            "today", "bring", "happen", "without", "before", "large", "million", "under", "water", "write",
            "mother", "national", "money", "story", "young", "month", "different", "right", "study", "though",
            "business", "issue", "black", "little", "house", "after", "since", "provide", "service", "around",
            "friend", "important"};
    Random randGen = new Random();

    public HangmanGame(int totalLives) {
        this.wordToGuess = getRandomWord();
        this.livesUsed = 0;
        this.totalLives = totalLives;
        this.lettersGuessed = new HashSet<>();
    }

    public char getNextGuess(Scanner inputReader) {
        char newchar = '?';
        System.out.print("Enter your new guess> ");
        boolean isLetterGuessedNew = false;
        while (!Character.isLetter(newchar) && !isLetterGuessedNew) {
            newchar = inputReader.next().charAt(0);
            if (!Character.isLetter(newchar)) {
                System.out.print("Your character must be a letter.  Please try again> ");
            } else if (lettersGuessed.contains(newchar)) {
                System.out.print("You've already guessed letter '" + newchar + "'.  Please try again> ");
                isLetterGuessedNew = false;
            } else {
                isLetterGuessedNew = true;
                lettersGuessed.add(newchar);
            }
        }
        return Character.toLowerCase(newchar);
    }

    public String getNewGameWord() {
        return getRandomWord();
    }

    public String getRandomWord() {
        int index = randGen.nextInt(wordList.length);
        return wordList[index];
    }

    public String getWordAsSymbols(String gameWord, Character character) {
        char[] starredCharArray = new char[gameWord.length()];
        Arrays.fill(starredCharArray, character);
        return new String(starredCharArray);
    }

    public String updateDisplayCharacters(char letterGuessed, String wordToGuess, String displayCharacters) {
        char[] wordAsArray = wordToGuess.toCharArray();
        char[] displayCharsAsArray = displayCharacters.toCharArray();

        for (int i=0; i<wordAsArray.length; i++){
            if (wordAsArray[i] == letterGuessed) {
                // update displayChars
                displayCharsAsArray[i] = letterGuessed;
            }
        }

        return displayCharacters;
    }

    public void updateLivesLeft(char letterGuessed, String wordToGuess) {
        String letterGuessedAsString = new String(new char[]{letterGuessed});
        if (!wordToGuess.contains(letterGuessedAsString)) {
            livesUsed +=1;
        }
    }

    public static boolean isGameOver(HangmanGame game, Character blankSymbol, String displayCharacters) {
        return !game.isWordGuessed(displayCharacters, blankSymbol) && game.hasLivesLeft();
    }

    public boolean hasLivesLeft() {
        return totalLives>livesUsed;
    }

    public boolean isWordGuessed(String displayCharacters, Character blankSymbol) {
        return !displayCharacters.contains(blankSymbol.toString());
    }

    public int getLivesLeft() {
        return totalLives - livesUsed;
    }
}
```